# make paragraph change on hover with css only

Tags: html, css

**Design:**
I created a div with changing backgrounds depending on hover state, with the paragraph floating within slightly higher than its parent, so that when "before" and "after" are declared, it looks clean and seamless.

**Problem:**
I'm trying to get my desired divs to grow and collapse whenever hovered. However when I try to modify the paragraph to resize inside with the div, nothing happens. I tried several experiments to see what works, and I can't get the desired effect. ***The text sits perfectly when expanded, but refuses to change or be modified when not.*** In other words my problem isn't in the hovering, but the text. It just wont let me resize it or force it to change margin or padding size on hover. And I think the before and after tags may be overlapping the text, regardless of the z-index I give them. You can see an image example of the problem and desired affect, as well as the jsfiddle below. *(under the code)*

**Code:**

```
    .con-1
{
    background:url(con-2.png) no-repeat;
    display:compact;
    margin-top:15px;
    margin-left:50px;
    position:relative;
    width:928px;
    height:140px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    overflow:hidden;

}



.con-1::before
{
    content:"";
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    width:928px;
    height:159px;
    background:url(con-1-top-4.png) no-repeat center center;
    left:4px;
    top:-159px;

}

.con-1::after
{
    content:"";
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    width:928px;
    height:65px;
    top:65px;
    background:url(con-1-bot-4.png) no-repeat;
    margin-bottom:50px;

}

 .con-1:hover
{
    height:100%;
    overflow:visible;
    background:url(con-1-mid-4.png) repeat-y;
    margin-top:170px;
    margin-bottom:100px;
}

 .con-1 p{
    margin-top:-290px;
    position:float;
    padding-left:120px;
    padding-right:250px;
    margin-bottom:-100px;
    z-index:200;
    overflow:visible;
}
```

**Picture example here:** http://1drv.ms/1sVJKkp

**Jsfiddle here:** http://jsfiddle.net/eradrom/6YNjw/

**Details:**
Ok, I've been working on a journal skin project for deviantart.com for a while, (which is a site that only allows CSS changes in coding and the commands and codes allowed are extremely limited) and I ran into several bumps in the road. I managed to get most of it working except the little problem I described. I’m at my wits end on this. Hopefully a solution can be given without having to create another div.

**IMPORTANT:** the site doesn’t allow the use if forms or input tags even labels, so that won’t work either. I’ve tried and checked that already.

Comment: Please share an example of your HTML and perhaps how your are currently doing the hover. A fiddle would be good too: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: ok here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eradrom/6YNjw/          if I did anything wrong let me know cause its my first time using the site. Anyway as it show there, hovering over is fine, its nestling the content before hand that doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the margin of .con-1 p to the same negative margin as the .con-1 and then use the selector .con-1:hover p to change the margin of the p element.

**CSS**

```
.con-1:hover p {
    margin-top:-290px;
}

 .con-1 p {
    margin-top:-159px;
    position:float;
    padding-left:120px;
    padding-right:250px;
    margin-bottom:-100px;
    z-index:200;
    overflow:visible;
}
```

**UPDATE**

I have forked your jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/HX4hH/ the changes are below
Your images don't show up so I have used colored block instead.

```
.con-1
{
    background:green;
    display:compact;
    margin-top:15px;
    margin-left:50px;
    position:relative;
    width:928px;
    height:140px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    overflow:hidden;

}

.con-1:before
{
    content:"";
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    width:928px;
    height:159px;
    background:red;
    left:4px;
    top:-159px;

}

.con-1:after
{
    content:"";
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    width:928px;
    height:65px;
    top:0px;
    background:yellow;
}

 .con-1:hover
{
    height:auto;
    overflow:visible;
    background:blue;
    margin-top:170px;
    margin-bottom:100px;
}
.con-1:hover p {
    margin-top:-290px;
    overflow: visible;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I'll give it another try, but I don't know if it will work. I think the before and after tags are overlapping the p regardless of the z-index I give them. Making the hover work on text in p from the beginning useless. I manged to get it to work one time, but only after adding so much text that neither the before and after were overlapping the middle of the div p, letting me place the mouse over it in the center. Truly, I'm at a loss.

Comment: I have forked your jsfiddle here: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/HX4hH/)

See above for changes

Comment: Ok, thanks  you so much for this! I tried it with the images I originally attached, and with a few tweaks of my own, I finally got it to work! thanks again! I'll upload the working version later if ya wanna look.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `overflow: visible;` on `.con-1 p`, which contains the text. This should hide the content when it its containing div is not expanded. With `overflow: visible;`, you are showing the overflow even though the div is "minimized."

Also you should know that `position: float;` is not valid HTML. If you want something to float, the property itself is `float`. You would set it to `float: left;`, for example. Valid types of `position` include `relative`, `fixed`, `absolute`, and `static` (this is the default).

Comment: ok I'll give it a try, but it really doesn't want to give me the desired affect or behavior I desire while expanded unless I use position:float. I know its not valid, but for some stupid reason it wont work any other way. And thanks for noticing the typo mistake on .con-1 p with the overflow. I'll fix on the original right away!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the css transitions like in this w3school example

http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transition1

I hope this helps!

Comment: well not yet, since I want to fix this problem first, before adding a transition animation. thanks for the advice though!